# Статические переменные в функциях

Tags: c++, c

Код:

```
double call_by_name(const char *name, int arg) {
    static const char *names[] = {"sin", "cos", "tan", NULL};
    static double (*fp[])(double) = {sin, cos, tan};

    for (int i = 0; names[i] != NULL; i++)
        if (strcmp(names[i], name) == 0)
            return ((*fp[i])(arg));

    return 0;
}
```

Почему здесь массивы `*names[]` и `*fp[]` имеют ключевое слово `static`? Для чего оно нужно в данном контексте?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Локальные `static` объекты инициализируются при первом вызове функции и существуют до конца жизни программы (хотя и доступна только внутри функции). Объявление как `static` в данном случае исключает создание и инициализацию массивов при ***каждом*** вызове функции. Т.е. при многократных вызовах функции можно сэкономить на процедуре инициализации, но при этом потеряем в используемой памяти.

Пример `с++`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g() { printf("g\n"); return 42; }

void f()
{
    static int i = g();
}

int main()
{
    f();
    f();
    f();
}
```

`g` будет выполнено только 1 раз.

А вот для `c` данный код не соберется вовсе, т.к. `c` требует для инициализации статических объектов констант времени компиляции.

Comment: А вот если я эту функцию вызываю всего лишь 1 раз во время работы программы, то быстродействие только уменьшается? Ведь в данном случае будет занята какая-то область памяти и она будет 'висеть' до конца работы программы?

Comment: Имеет ли смысл ко всем переменным, которые я создаю в функциях применять слово 'static'?

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий при однократном вызове особого смысла в использовании `static` я не вижу.

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий статические переменные размещаются в специальной области памяти чуть ниже констант. На быстродействие не влияет, но как и любой сингтон это фактически утечка, рассчитанная на этапе архитекстуры.

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий к слову, `static` вне функции, например для глобальной переменной, имеет несколько другой смысл.

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий применять ко всем переменным - это хуже чем даже делать глобальными (с точки зрения памяти, да и читабельность страдает).

Comment: @pavel, а о какой здесь утечке может идти речь? Я просто всегда утечку представлял, как: пишешь 'new' , но забываешь написать 'delete' ...(не совсем ещё понимаю значение синглтон в контексте...)

Comment: @pavel, а в каких случаях тогда следует использовать?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian у `static` вообще много смыслов в зависимости от контекста: локальные, глобальные, члены класса (функции, данные).

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий, можете рассматривать статические переменные, как глобальные, но с ограниченной областью видимости. Основное их свойство -- это сохранение значения  между вызовами функций, в отличие от локальных, располагаемых в стеке и поэтому существующих только во время активности функции, где они определены.

Comment: говорят, в FORTRAN все "автоматические" переменные висели в статической памяти, поэтому стек-фреймы не нужно было считать. Потому и "быстрые вычисления" =)