# Реализация множественного создания текстовых файлов в функции

Tags: c++, классы, потоки-данных

### Первый вопрос

Допустим, есть функция `Func()`. Каким образом можно реализовать создание отдельного текстового файла `out` с именем `имя_файла.txt` с помощью потоков при каждом вызове функции?

```
ofstream out;
out.open("имя_файла.txt");
```

но так, чтобы к имени файла каждый раз добавлялась цифра (порядковый номер), по типу `имя_файла_1.txt` при первом вызове функции, `имя_файла_2.txt` при втором вызове.

### Второй вопрос

Пользователь вводит путь к файлу, например `D:\Документы\input.txt`. Программа считывает это, но при попытке открыть такой файл по этому пути, появится ошибка будто файл не открыт.

```
cout << "Type full path to the file" << endl;
gets_s(path);
ifstream dump;
dump.open(path);
if (!dump.is_open()) cout << "File is not opened" << endl;
```

Каким образом такую ошибку исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В решении **первого вопроса** может помочь функция [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Кроме того, стоит воспользоваться такой возможностью, как [статическая переменная в функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556728/227016). Таким образом, чтобы создать файл с именем `имя_файла_<i>.txt` нужно написать:

```
void func() {
//  это статическая переменная
//  она имеет тип atomic_*, чтобы при вызове нашей функции из разных потоков не получались файлы с одинаковыми именами
    static atomic_size_t numberFiles;
    size_t currentFileIndex = numberFiles++;
    ofstream out("имя_файла" + to_string(currentFileIndex) + ".txt");

    ...
}
```

**Второй вопрос** не очень понятный. Если пользователь ввёл имя файла, а такого файла не существует, то значит пользователь ошибся с именем файла. Можно сообщить ему об этом, например так:

```
while (!dump.is_open()) {
    cout << "Такого файла не существует" << endl;
    cout << "Пожалуйста, введите правильное имя файла:" << endl;
    getline(cin, path);
    dump.open(path);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Со вторым разобрался, путь к файлу был прописан кириллицей и компилятор не воспринимал ее. Добавил в начале файла:
`#include <windows.h>`
а в коде :
`SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);`